# Why $\texttt{Sqrt}[\textrm{positive value}] > 0$ sometimes simplifies to true, sometimes not

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

Why this does not evaluate to `True`:

```
Assuming[-2 bRis bRm2 + (aRx rho + vR0)^2 > 0, Simplify[Sqrt[-2 bRis bRm2 + 
  (aRx rho + vR0)^2] > 0, reals]]
(* Sqrt[-2 bRis bRm2 + (aRx rho + vR0)^2] > 0 *)
```

if this does:

```
Assuming[-2 bRis bRm2 > 0, Simplify[Sqrt[-2 bRis bRm2] > 0]]
(* True *)
```

The second case would imply that `Sqrt` uses only the principal root.

Comment: Instead of reals, use Reals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would also use `Reduce`. It tries harder than `Simplify` or `FullSimplify`.

For instance:

```
Assuming[-2 bRis bRm2 + (aRx rho + vR0)^2 > 0, 
 Simplify@
  Reduce[Implies[$Assumptions, 
    Sqrt[-2 bRis bRm2 + (aRx rho + vR0)^2] > 0]]
 ]

(*  True  *)
```

Or simply:

```
Assuming[-2 bRis bRm2 + (aRx rho + vR0)^2 > 0, 
  Reduce[Implies[$Assumptions, 
    Sqrt[-2 bRis bRm2 + (aRx rho + vR0)^2] > 0], Reals]
 ]

(*  True  *)
```

Or equivalently:

```
Reduce[
 Implies[
  -2 bRis bRm2 + (aRx rho + vR0)^2 > 0,
  Sqrt[-2 bRis bRm2 + (aRx rho + vR0)^2] > 0
  ],
 Reals]

(*  True  *)
```

Answer (score 5):

If you solve inequality `Reduce` is better:

```
Reduce[Sqrt[-2 b1 b2 + (a r + v)^2] > 0 && -2 b1 b2 + (a r + v)^2 > 
   0 && a > 0 && b1 > 0 && b2 > 0 && r > 0 && v > 0]

(*  v > 0 && r > 0 && a > 0 && b2 > 0 && 
 0 < b1 < (a^2 r^2 + 2 a r v + v^2)/(2 b2)  *)
```

If you use `Reals` insted of what I did, you get an answer, but it will be considerably longer. That's why I did not do it.

Have fun!